# passing JavaScript variable to Django

Tags: javascript, django, syntax

How can I pass a js variable to Django?

I have this simple code:

```
$(".update_btn").click(function() {
 var row_id=$(this).attr("row_id")
```

I want to pass row_id as index to a Django parameter called `ticket_row`, so that I could have `ticket_row[row_id][1]`
I started to pass the first index with

```
console.log("{{ ticket_row['" + row_id + "'] }}")
```

but it's working correctly. 
So, I need some help here :)

Any one has any suggestion / solution?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you wanting to send this in a form, or some other way?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use AJAX to send a request to the server. Or you could redirect the user to the page with an additional GET parameter: `/path/to/page.html?row_id=2`, replacing `2` with the ID you receive in JavaScript. Then access it via the request in your view:

```
def index(request):
    . . .
    row_id = 0
    if "row_id" in request.GET:
        row_id = int(request.GET["row_id"])
    try:
        selected_row = ticket_row[row_id]
    except IndexError:
        selected_row = ticket_row[0]
    return render(request, self.template_name, {"selected_row": selected_row})
```

In your template, you would then use:

```
console.log("{{ selected_row }}")
```